# What is error "Get-AnsibleWindowsWebRequestSpec"?

Tags: ansible, ftp

I am trying a test to upload a .txt file from a FTP server to a Windows client with Ansible using `ansible.windows.win_get_url` module like this:

Playbook:

```yaml
hosts: win
gather_facts: no
tasks:
- name: Download file through FTP
  ansible.windows.win_get_url:
    url: ftp://10.30.103.3/FLAG.txt
    dest: '%TEMP%/FLAG.txt'
    url_username: test
    url_password: azerty
```

In the output, at the end when trying:

```
ansible-playbook test_ftp.yml > error.txt
```

I get the error:

```
"msg": "Unhandled exception while executing module: The term 'Get-AnsibleWindowsWebRequestSpec' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."
```

I installed the modules using

```
ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.windows
```

I'm using Ansible 2.9.

Comment: and when you replace the task with `win_get_url` instead of `ansible.windows.win_get_url`, what output you get?

Comment: Indeed, up until 2.9, the fully qualified names where not a thing in Ansible: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/win_get_url_module.html. As it looks, there Ansible tries to translate it into a PowerShell command, because your error really looks like one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error was the Windows task in the playbook, changed from `ansible.windows.win_get_url` to `win_get_url`.

Comment: This also applies to ansible.windows.win_package.  Use win_package instead